# What's the naming convention for a function that returns a function?

Tags: naming-conventions

```
function getPerformActionFunction(someParameter) {
    return function() { 
        performAction(someParameter);
    }
}
```

What would you call `getPerformActionFunction` to indicate that it doesn't perform the action, but rather returns a function which performs the action?

Example is Javascript, and if there's a Javascript convention that's preferred, but also interested in other languages if the answer differs.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if it's in any style guides, but I quite like the `-er` suffix to suggest something that is able to do an action.

e.g. `getActionPerformer` or `fooHandler` or `XMLTransformer`

I've used this sort of style in C#, Java and Clojure an it seems to work OK.